# Why is my dummy variable conversion in Stata producing: type mismatch?

Tags: stata

I am attempting a simple replacement of the string "Female" with dummy values, 1 & 0. 
I understand that transforming from string is not allowed. So I attempted to make the conversion in the following way:

```
    replace female =1 if female=="Female"
```

and this way

```
    replace female = "1" if female == "Female"
```

but both spit out the error term:

```
type mismatch
r(109);
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, I was sure the second code listed would work.

Answer (score 2):

The implication is that the variable `female`, contrary to your report, is numeric. It may have value labels attached.

You don't give a data example, or even the report from a `describe`, but both errors can be reproduced.

```
. clear

. set obs 2
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 2

. gen female = cond(_n == 1, 1, 0)

. label def female 1 female 0 male

. label val female female

. list

     +--------+
     | female |
     |--------|
  1. | female |
  2. |   male |
     +--------+

. replace female = "1" if female == "female"
type mismatch
r(109);

. replace female = 1 if female == "female"
type mismatch
r(109);

. d female

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
female          float   %9.0g      female
```

The reason for failure is different, even though the error message is the same.

```
. replace female = "1" if female == "female"
 type mismatch
 r(109);
```

This fails because you are trying to replace the value of `female` with the string `"1"`, but `female` is a numeric variable. Stata does not get as far as the comparison of `female` with the string `"female"`, which would fail for the same reason.

```
. replace female = 1 if female == "female"
type mismatch
r(109);
```

Trying to `replace female` with the numeric value `1` is fine, but the test `if female == "female"` is out of order because the variable `female` is numeric.

There is still the question of what you are trying to do and why. From a Stata point of view, an ideal indicator variable

(a) is 1 or 0

(b) has value labels assigned

(c) is named for the state with value 1, so is named `female` if and only the value 1 means female.

Hence it may be that you don't need to do anything here.

I've heard repeated stories of presenters being asked which way their indicators `gender` or `sex` went and not knowing, which is a serious gaffe. Much more discussion can be found in [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099).

Comment: Thanks @Nick Cox; to answer your question, I am trying to code the variable female as a 1 or a 0. I

Comment: As said, on the evidence it is already numeric. As said, without a `describe` or `summarize` report or a data example I can't say more. I think you'd be better off on Statalist where more eyes are watching, including in your time zone.

Comment: I think I answered your question; otherwise please tell me more.

Comment: You might find it helpful to use `list, nolabel` to view the underlying values of your variables.